# How to implement communication between consumer and producer with fast and slow workers?

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, rpc, soa, event-driven

I'm looking for a pattern and existing implementations for my situation:
I have synchronous soa which uses REST APIs, in fact I implement remote procedure call with REST. And I have got some slow workers which process requests for substantial time (around 30 seconds) and due to some license constraints for some requests I can process them only sequentially (see [system setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceKk2.jpg)).

What are recommended ways to implement communication for such case?

How can I mix synchronous and asynchronous communication in the situation when the consumer is behind firewall and I cannot send him notification about completed tasks easily and I might not be able to let consumer use my message broker if I have one?

Workers are implemented in Python using Flask and gunicorn. At the moment I'm using synchronous REST interfaces and allow for the delay as I only had fast workers. I looked at Kafka and RabbitMq and they would fit for backend side 
communication, however how does producer communicate with the consumer?

If the consumer fires API request my producer can return code 202, then how shall producer notify consumer that result is available? Will consumer have to poll the producer for results?

Also if I use message brokers and my gateway acts on behalf of consumer, it should have a registry of requests (I already have GUID for every request now) and results, which approach would you recommend for implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Producer- agent which produces the message
Consumer - agent which can handle the message and implement the logic for processing the message
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, basically you suggest to implement polling mechanism. Are there better alternatives like websockets to notify about results? 
Can you point to some projects@github?

Comment: polling is easier to implement than websockets and involves just REST API development efforts. Having said that using websockets or gRPC would be ideal. https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#websocket https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/node-js-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial-2def3a841b61